# How redirect by .htaccess dynamic nested URL

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

How use write rule?

I need to redirect

```
www.example.com/accesories
```

to

```
www.example.com/accesories/item
```

**UPDATE:** If I use `Redirect /accesories /accesories/items` I receive:

> `www.example.com//accesories/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/`

Comment: What's the "dynamic" part? What have you tried? This looks like a straight forward redirect? What's the specific problem you are having? What other directives do you have?

Comment: If I use       Redirect /accesories /accesories/items I receive www.example.com//accesories/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/items/

Comment: "dynamic" - because accesories is a category with produkcts but I dont want show wyhos products a need to redirect to /accesories/items

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Redirect /accesories /accesories/items
> ```

Yes, that will result in a redirect loop because the mod_alias `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching, as per [the Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) (highlighting my own):

> ...any request **beginning with** URL-path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. **Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.**

If you want to redirect just that specific URL then you would need to use the `RedirectMatch` directive<sup>***1**</sup> instead, that matches against a regex. For example:

```
RedirectMatch ^/accesories$ /accesories/items
```

<sup>***1**</sup> Unless you are already using mod_rewrite in other directives (which is why I asked "What other directives do you have?") in which case it may be preferable to use mod_rewrite instead.

> "dynamic" - because accesories is a category with produkcts but I dont want show wyhos products a need to redirect to /accesories/items

I'm not too sure what you mean by this, but if need to redirect `/accesories/<products>` to `/accesories/items`, where `<products>` can be any single path segment, except for `items` then you would need to do something like the following using a negative lookahead in the `RedirectMatch` directive (or use mod_rewrite). For example:

```
RedirectMatch ^/accesories(/(?!items)[^/]*)?$ /accesories/items
```

The above redirects `/accesories`, `/accesories/` and `/accesories/<anything>`, but not `/accesories/items` (because that would create a redirect-loop) to `/accesories/items`.

Note that these are 302 (temporary) redirects. (Always test with 302s to avoid potential caching issues and only change to 301 later if that is the intention.)

The order of directives in `.htaccess` can be important. External redirects generally need to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file.